# Orthogonal and differentiable wavelet basis for Hilbert Space of $L^2$ complex-functions and weighted inner product

Tags: complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, wavelets

I am looking for an orthogonal wavelet basis for a Hilbert Space $H$ of complex-valued square-integrable functions defined over the non-negative numbers. The inner product on $H$ is the weighted inner product:

$$\langle f; g \rangle_{w} = \int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \,\overline{g(x)}\, w(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

where $w$ is a positive function of $x$, $x \geq 0$, and $f, g \in H$. Additionally, I have the constraint that my wavelets are twice differentiable. Could someone suggest such a wavelet basis?

Comment: A more clear examplr would be the shannon wavelets. Perfect boxes in the fourier domaim

Comment: Is the Shannon wavelet basis an orthogonal basis under the $\langle \cdot; \cdot \rangle_w$ inner product for every $w$?